# Building host on macOS Sierra

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, virtualbox, macos-sierra

i have installed visual studio 2017 in my windows10 ..I want to build an ios app in windows10 using xamarin.IOS.For that I am running macOS Sierra on oracle virtual box and building host from this VM mac.I am unable to find in my Xamarin Mac Agent in windows10.Can anyone help with this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Remote iOS Simulator.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

Comment: I dont have a macbook or any apple device..Can you help me out?

Comment: There is no need for a macbook to program for iOS. All you need to do is install an iOS emulator on your windows. No links I've submitted explain how to do it.

Comment: Xamarin is asking me to do build host process for compiling the app..I have ipadian installed in my windows10.

Comment: Can you help me out ASAP please??

Comment: I'm researching a way to solve your problem. Usually as an IDE for mobile development companion emulator system that is developed, be it Android or iOS. Using ipadian, if it is not integrated with VS, you will have to compile your application and send it to the emulator, which makes development very difficult.

Comment: I have found that iOS apps development is almost impossible for person like me who doesn't have any apple product. I found a way,if we have an iPhone we can use some app,by which we can use our phone as emulator. In-short , I have to run Xcode and Xamarin on VM, but problem is that for oracle virtual box the screen size is too small for app development.